# StringTokenizer extraction limit

Tags: java, tokenize

I'm trying to extract file name in a text file. Currently, i'm using tokenizer. Somehow, not all of the file names is extracted correctly.

This is my code:

```
list = sc.nextLine();
token = new StringTokenizer(list,".txt");
newlist = token.nextToken();
```

This is what happen:
The token only extract "Kesiha" insted of "Kesihatan"

Solutions?

Comment: What about `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'))`?

Answer (score 1):

From the doc for StringTokenizer

"All characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens."

So Its splitting on the "t"